# Speed up updating items individually

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 12000 items in a table and I want to update and commit each item individually.

```
items = db.session.query(User).all()

for item in items:
    item.active = 0
    # do stuff
    db.session.commit()
```

I need to commit every iteration so that changes goes to database immediately.  If I select all rows in my first query the commit is slow.  If I select smaller set of data (400 rows for example) it is fast.

What should I do for better performance without selecting a smaller set of data?

Comment: *"I need to commit in every iteration, so changes goes to database immediately."* - why? If you're committing after every single update, you're not using the database they way it's meant to be used, this is always going to be slow.

Comment: For some reason i start "task" every night to detect — can user login to site or not. So i get all users and start to detect this. And i want to send this date to database as soon as possible to database.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible approach to access control for several reasons. But besides that, the question is what is "fast enough" in this context. And whether it takes 5s or 20s for a user to get deactivated surely won't matter if you're only checking once per day anyway. A `COMMIT` is several magnitudes more expensive than your `UPDATE`, you're unnecessarily delaying this process like this (*and* you're completely breaking [transactionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) as a side effect).

Comment: So: Update all your items in one go, and commit *once*. Use [savepoints](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint) if memory usage is becoming a concern. And don't fetch all records at once by doing `.all()`, simply iterate over the query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy caches all the queried items internally, but expires that cache when a `commit` is issued.  So the instance accessed in the next iteration is in the "expired" state and SQLAlchemy re-queries the database.  So you're effectively doing:

1. a *massive* query at the beginning for 12000 items
2. 12000 commits
3. 11999 queries for individual items
4. 24000 queries total

The difference you're seeing when you only select 400 the first time is merely an effect of scale: you only go through one third as many select/commit cycles.

There is no documented way to prevent the expiration mechanism from happening.  You can either put up with making 24000 queries, or you can commit once at the end.

You will most likely be better off just committing after the loop in one large transaction.